# User.Suspended always return false in octokit.net

Tags: github-api, octokit.net

I am using the following code to get a list of all GitHub Enterprise users, then I am trying to suspend those no longer in AD. The Suspend function works, but User.Suspended property always returns false.

```
var searhRequest = new SearchUsersRequest("type:user&page="+pageNumber+"&page_size=100");
                githubUsers = await client.Search.SearchUsers(searhRequest);   

 client.User.Administration.Suspend(userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think the problem is that we were trying to cast the return value as a user when ultimately the call that this is making behind the scenes doesn't return that data. As a work around, I've just called the get user method to get the users after I've rounded up the original results.

It can probably be done better, but here's what I have right now

```
Task<SearchUsersResult> task;
List<User> users = new List<User>();
int page = 1;

do
{
  task = github.Search.SearchUsers(new SearchUsersRequest("type:user&repos:>=0") { Page = page, PerPage = 500 });
  task.Wait();

  users.AddRange(task.Result.Items.ToList<User>());
  page++;
}
while (users.Count < task.Result.TotalCount);

// Get all users by login (this calls the api once for every user you have)
var tasks = users.Select(u => github.User.Get(u.Login));

// Get all unsuspended users
var activeUsers = Task.WhenAll<User>(tasks).Result.Where<User>(u => !u.Suspended).ToList();
```

Note that in the result of the call doesn't include the "isSuspended" data (pulled from my local enterprise instance using fiddler and then sanitized)

```
{"login":"User1"
"id":45
"avatar_url":"http://github.com/avatars/u/45?"
"gravatar_id":""
"url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1"
"html_url":"http://github.com/User1"
"followers_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/followers"
"following_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/following{/other_user}"
"gists_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/gists{/gist_id}"
"starred_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/starred{/owner}{/repo}"
"subscriptions_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/subscriptions"
"organizations_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/orgs"
"repos_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/repos"
"events_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/events{/privacy}"
"received_events_url":"http://github.com/api/v3/users/User1/received_events"
"type":"User"
"site_admin":false
"ldap_dn":"CN=User1
OU=CompanyDEVUsers
OU=Users
OU=Company
DC=Company
DC=com"
"score":1.0}
```